# SonarQubeでテストコードをチェック対象外としたい

Tags: java, sonarqube

SonarQube ver 6.2 を使っています。
IssuesにJUnitで書いたテストコードが色々引っかかって出てくる（例えばマジックナンバーを使っている、など）のですが、テストコードをチェックの対象外としたいです。
どうすればできるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sonar-scanner.propertiesに以下のいずれかを追加することで、除外できました。

sonar.exclusions=**/*Test.java
sonar.exclusions=src/test/**

正規表現の使用方法については、こちらに書いてあります。
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreFiles

※sonar.test.exclusionsというプロパティを使うべきかもしれませんが、想定通り動きませんでした。